# Copy a row to another DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, dataset, rows

I have two `DataGridViews` in Windows Form, VB.NET

When I double click on the `FullSelectedRow` of `DataGridView1`, the `SelectedRow` should be copied to the `DataGridView2`, both grids are `DataBounded` from SQL Server 2008..

Here is my code to retrieve the data in each grid..

```
**DataGridView1**
Dim UserScheduleString As String = "SELECT * FROM Schedule"
Dim UserScheduleStringList As New SqlCommand(UserScheduleString, mdl_Connection.CONN)

UserScheduleStringList.CommandType = CommandType.Text
UserScheduleStringListAdpt.SelectCommand = UserScheduleStringList
UserScheduleStringListAdpt.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
UserScheduleStringListAdpt.Fill(UserScheduleStringListDataSet, "Users")
DataGridView1.DataSource = UserScheduleStringListDataSet.Tables("Users")


**DataGridView2**
Dim SomeTableString As String = "SELECT * FROM someTable"
Dim SomeTableStringList As New SqlCommand(SomeTableString, mdl_Connection.CONN)

SomeTableStringList.CommandType = CommandType.Text
SomeTableStringListAdpt.SelectCommand = SomeTableStringList
SomeTableStringListAdpt.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
SomeTableStringListAdpt.FillSomeTableStringListDataSet, "*<tablename>*")
DataGridView1.DataSource = SomeTableStringListDataSet.Tables("*<tablename>*")
```

I've search over other forums and this is what I've got..

```
newCustomersRow = UserScheduleStringListDataSet.Tables("Users").NewRow()
newCustomersRow("ID") = "0023"
newCustomersRow("Day") = "Tuesday"
newCustomersRow("Start Time") = "13:00:00"
newCustomersRow("End Time") = "18:00:00"

UserScheduleStringListDataSet.Tables("Users").Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)

UserScheduleStringListAdpt.Update(UserScheduleStringListDataSet, "Users")
```

When I try to put this in `DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick`, it gives me an error of `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: Why you do not accept answers nor request further help?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) 

   Dim dr = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem, System.Data.DataRowView).Row

   UserScheduleStringListDataSet.Tables("Users").ImportRow(dr)

   UserScheduleStringListAdpt.Update(UserScheduleStringListDataSet, "Users")

End Sub
```

Comment: ImportRow is non a member of DataRowCollection

Comment: Corrected. It's on the datatable, not on the row collection.

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure that DataBoundItem is the bound DataRow (and therefore, castable to that type). But you can try, it should be OK.

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.